# Habilitar select con otro select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy trabajando con un *Select* y necesito que al seleccionar una opción se me habilite otro *select* que tengo que esta `disabled` intente lo siguiente pero no me funciono.

```
<div>
    <select id="lead_source" class="form-control" title="Fuente de plomo / Fonte de chumbo" name="leadsource">
                    <option selected="selected" value="Walk in">Walk in</option>
                    <option value="Social_Media" onclick="muestra_oculta();" >Social Media</option>
                    <option value="Phone Inquiry">Phone Inquiry</option>
                    <option value="Event">Event</option>
                  </select>     
</div>

<div >           
    <select id="Campaign_Source__c" class="form-control" name="Campaign_Source__c" disabled>
  <option selected disabled >Selecione</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="LinkedIn ">LinkedIn </option>
  <option value="YouTube ">YouTube </option>
                  </select>     
</div>

<script>
    let ee = document.getElementById('lead_source');
  ee.addEventListener("change", function(){
if (ee.value.toUpperCase() == 'Social_Media') {
    document.getElementById('Campaign_Source__c').disabled = false;
}else {
    document.getElementById('Campaign_Source__c').disabled = true;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es buena idea usar solo números para nombres de identificador y clases, aunque puede funcionar y tu problema no viene por ahí, pero es bueno tenerlo en cuenta para evitarte futuros dolores de cabeza.

Tu script no funciona porque `if (ee.value.toUpperCase() == 'Social_Media') {` estás convirtiendo a mayúsculas (SOCIAL_MEDIA) y comparando el valor seleccionado sin modificar (Social_Media), quita `.toUpperCase()`.

También sobra el `onclick="muestra_oculta();`, porque el segundo select se muestra u oculta de acuerdo al valor seleccionado en el primero.

```js
let ee = document.getElementById('lead_source');
let cs = document.getElementById('Campaign_Source__c');
ee.addEventListener("change", function(){
    if (ee.value == 'Social_Media') {
        cs.disabled = false;
    }else {
        cs.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <select id="lead_source" class="form-control" title="Fuente de plomo / Fonte de chumbo" name="leadsource">
                    <option selected="selected" value="Walk in">Walk in</option>
                    <option value="Social_Media">Social Media</option>
                    <option value="Phone Inquiry">Phone Inquiry</option>
                    <option value="Event">Event</option>
                  </select>     
</div>

<div >           
    <select id="Campaign_Source__c" class="form-control" name="Campaign_Source__c" disabled>
  <option selected disabled >Selecione</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="LinkedIn ">LinkedIn </option>
  <option value="YouTube ">YouTube </option>
                  </select>     
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu respuesta, y si tueviera texto seria como lo tengo arriba? es que lo puse asi para que quedara mas faci de entender con numero pero en realidad lleva texto y poseo el problema que no lo recnoce no se si es por los id son muchos caracteres y con espacios esto influye? gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Los `id` y los `name` no pueden contener nombre espacios. Un identificador en JavaScript tiene que empezar con una letra, un guión bajo (_) o un símbolo de dólar ($); los valores subsiguientes puede ser números. Debido a que JavaScript diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, las letras incluyen tanto desde la "A" hasta la "Z" (mayúsculas) como de la "a" hasta la "z". https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

Comment: @IvanSuarez, edita la pregunta y coloca un ejemplo REAL de lo que pretendes hacer, para evitar respuestas basadas en suposiciones.

Comment: ya la edite con lo que realmente requiero por alguna razon el js no funciona gracias y saludos.

Comment: Listo, ya actualicé la respuesta con tus nuevos datos.

Comment: sabes por que cuando lo pongo el un html no me funciona?
debo enlazar alguna js ?
gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Lo más probable es que estés ejecutando el script antes de que el DOM se haya cargado. Coloca el script hasta abajo, antes de `</body>` o colócalo dentro de una función `window.onload` o, mejor aún, dentro de ´window.addEventListener('load', ...)´

Answer (score 0):

> Claro en caso que tus id contengan numeros y letras aqui te dejo un ejemplo

```js
let ee = document.getElementById('1');
ee.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  if (ee.value.toUpperCase() === 'TP_02') {
    document.getElementById('2').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('2').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="1" name="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="Walk in">ejemplo</option>
    <option value="TP_01">1</option>
    <option value="tp_02">2</option>
    <option value="TP_03">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select id="2" class="form-control" name="2" disabled>
    <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```