# Hola.. necesito ayuda con selet

Tags: php, html5, select

**Tengo 3 select y lo que quiero es que cuando marque una los otros dos se desactiven**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="content" class="solicitante center-block form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;">
                      <!--<label>Sistemas:</label>-->
                     <select id="sistemas" name="sistemas" class="form-control input-lg">
                         <option value=""  >SELECCIONE UNA OPCION</option>
                         <option value="a1">CREACION DE USUARIOS</option>
                         <option value="a2">CAMBIO/RESETEO DE CLAVE</option>
                         <option value="a3">DESHABILITACION DE USUARIO</option>
                         <option value="a4">INSTALACION DE SISTEMA</option>
                         <option value="a5">ACTUALIZACION DE SISTEMA</option>
                         <option value="a6">OTROS</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>

                <div id="content2" class="div2 solicitante form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;">
                <!-- <label>Equipos:</label>-->
                 <select name="equipos" class="form-control input-lg">
                     <option value=""  >Seleccione Una Opcion</option>
                     <?php
                        include '../conexion/conexion2.php';
                        $consulta="SELECT * FROM equipos";
                        $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
                      ?>
                     <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones):?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $opciones['nombre']?> "><?php echo $opciones['nombre']?></option>
                     <?php endforeach ?>
                 </select>
              </div>
              <div id="content3" class="div3 solicitante form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;">
                 <!--<label>Redes:</label>-->
                 <select name="redes" class="form-control input-lg" >
                     <option value=""  >SELECCIONE UNA OPCION</option>
                     <?php
                        include '../conexion/conexion2.php';
                        $consulta="SELECT * FROM redes";
                        $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
                      ?>
                     <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones):?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $opciones['nombre']?> "><?php echo $opciones['nombre']?></option>
                     <?php endforeach ?>
                 </select>
               </div>
            </div>
```

*por el momento estoy ocultando con check pero no me gustan como esta funcionano por que de igual manera puede elegir dos seelct y yo solo quiero que me marque una opcion de los tres dejo como ejemplo mi select espero que entiendan mi pedido*

Comment: Explica mejor tu duda por favor

Comment: y en mi pagina tengo tres tipos de select que el usuario me tinen que marcar una sola de los tres select deacuerdo a su solicitud. entonces al seleccionar una lista de los otros dos select restantes se desactive para que no marque dos solicitudes a la vez

Comment: ¿podrias explicarlo mejor? Segun yo entiendo que sean select dinamicos, o dependientes uno del otro, si uno no esta lleno no puedes cambiar el otro? o como? a como entiendo porque no optas por  un **radio button**   que este a su vez despliegue una **text area** si requiere descripcion mas detallada o unos **select** dependientes de un **radio button**

Comment: Tal vez acá esté algo que te acerque a resolver tu problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362284/habilitar-select-con-otro-select